# pointers to compare objects for equality c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

Since pointers are integers, the idea is that if

```
Object* one = new SameObject();
Object* two = one;
```

then if I compare `one` to `two`, I will get true.

Can I use this to compare two such objects for equality? Can this be used as a guarantee of equality? Are objects moved in the heap at any point after initialization?

Comment: `SameObject` is a variable, it's not allocated in the heap. Heap data is allocated with `new` or `malloc()`.

Comment: When a programmer sees two pointers compared, they expect that two pointers are being compared.  Any other behavior will just get you strange looks.

Comment: I used it to implement a connected graph of objects. I realize now that it wasn't the way to do it.

Comment: Pointers are not integers. If pointers are integers, we should be able to divide pointers. We cannot. Example: `int X = 4, * Xp = &X, * Yp = Xp / 10;`

Comment: Not an integer in the sense integer datatype, but it is a memory address which is a number, an unsigned integer. And you can add / subtract pointers with numbers -- it's called pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use this to compare two such objects for equality?

It's not recommended.  Because equality is generally not construed to mean "it's the same object".  Two different integers (occupy different memory addresses) that both contain the value 4 are considered equal.

> Can this be used as a guarantee of equality?

No, as explained above

> Are objects moved in the heap at any point after initialization?

It's not clear what you mean here.  But I think what you mean is an object, once created on the heap, does it ever move.  The answer is, yes.  For example, if you keep inserting objects into a std::vector via push_back().  Since a vector's items must be contiguous, if it runs out of space, it will allocated a new bigger space and copy all the old values into the new space.  So, yes, all of those heap allocated objects will now be in a new location.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you!

Comment: This is not overly correct. Objects once created, technically are not moved. However, they can be copied over to the new location (possibly invoking move constructor!), and the former object is than destroyed. While the difference is subtle, it does exist.

Comment: Either or, pointers are very unreliable for object comparison is the conclusion, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you're comparing global or static variables, no two variables can have the same address, and they're never moved. So if the addresses are equal, the pointers must refer to the same variables, and the values will be equal.

For local variables, this will only be true as long as you have not returned from the function that declared the variables. The addresses of local variables are only valid while that function call is in progress. It's very possible that after you return from one function, and then call some other function, that the address of a variable in the first function may compare equal to a variable in the second function. Any use of addresses of variables from a function that has returns results in undefined behavior.

Similarly, the address of a heap-allocated object (created with `new` or `malloc()`) will only be valid until the object is deleted (with `delete` or `free()`). Heap objects are not moved (or if they are, it should be transparent to the program). But if you delete an object, and then create a new object, the new object could get the address of the deleted one.